# Calling Webservice with authentication using vbscript

Tags: web-services, authentication, vbscript

How do I get username and password in webservice when I use vbscript code as below.

```
call oXMLHTTP.open("POST","http://localhost:11883/ServiceCall.asmx/GetEmloyee,false,testUser,testPasword)
```

Comment: What authentication scheme does the web service expect? NTLM? Basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code example is correct.

From the [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924068.aspx):

`oXMLHttpRequest.open(bstrMethod, bstrUrl, varAsync, bstrUser, bstrPassword);`

Answer (score 2):

You must also call the [`send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763706(VS.85).aspx) method after calling [`open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757849(VS.85).aspx).